# controllerの中で同じ処理を一定回数繰り返したい

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

AngularJSでtodoアプリをつくっています。controllerの中で同じ処理を複数回繰り返す処理を書いています。

現状では５回繰り返す仕様になっていて、そこまで多くはないのでベタ書きしているのですが、今後の拡張性などを考えるともっと簡潔に書きたいです。

以下がそのコードです。一部省略していますがだいたいこのような感じです。angular.forEachをつかうのかな...と思ったのですがうまくできませんでした... Angularは初心者なのでまだまだ全然わかっていません... どうかよろしくお願いいたします。

```
$scope.init = ->

  # contentを7件生成する
  $scope.newContent = { title: '', description: '' }
  Content.save($scope.newContent).$promise.then (response) ->
    console.info "[info] new content saved."
  Content.save($scope.newContent).$promise.then (response) ->
    console.info "[info] new content saved."
  Content.save($scope.newContent).$promise.then (response) ->
    console.info "[info] new content saved."
  Content.save($scope.newContent).$promise.then (response) ->
    console.info "[info] new content saved."
  Content.save($scope.newContent).$promise.then (response) ->
    console.info "[info] new content saved."

  # 以下省略...
  return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`angular.forEach`は配列やオブジェクトに対してループ処理を実行します。
http://angularjsninja.com/blog/2013/12/06/angular-foreach/

本質問の件は、単純なforループでいけます。

```
...
$scope.newContent = { title: '', description: '' }
# n回繰り返す
n = 5
for i in [1..n]
  Content.save($scope.newContent).$promise.then (response) ->
    console.info "[info] new content saved."
...
```